# Jest: Function to format currency values

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, currency

I'm having the following error when testing a function to format currency values

Function:

```
const brlCurrencyFormatting = (value) => {
  const options = {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'};
  return value.toLocaleString('pt-BR', options);
}
```

Test:

```
test('Should format the number 9000 and return R$ 9.000,00', () => {
    const value = 9000;
    const formattedValue = brlCurrencyFormatting(value);
    expect(formattedValue).toBe('R$ 9.000,00');
  });
```

Error:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "R$ 9.000,00"
    Received: "R$ 9.000,00"

      5 |     const value = 9000;
      6 |     const formattedValue = brlCurrencyFormatting(value);
    > 7 |     expect(formattedValue).toBe('R$ 9.000,00');
        |                            ^
      8 |   });
      9 | });
```

Comment: It's the space character in your expected string. The Intl library uses non-breaking spaces, ASCII 160

Comment: Thank you very much Phil! After your comment I was able to work around the situation, implementing this code that "removes" non-breaking spaces: `replace(/\s/g, ' ')`